# QtCreator (version 4.11) UI is impossible to read

Tags: qt, qt-creator, dpi

I have tried playing `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` environment variable and it does not fix things for me, it changes things, but to the worse. I have been running `Qt Creator` on the same system with the same monitors (4K, 150% scaling) for 2 years. `Qt Creator` was fine. All of a sudden I come to this, which is extremely annoying. It's either a result of Windows update or `Qt Creator` has messed something up. Does anyone know the workaround?

[image]

Comment: try with `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1`, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#high-dpi-support-in-qt

Comment: @eyllanesc, no result whatsoever. Setting QT_SCALE_FACTOR does have affect, but creates more issue.

Comment: I recommend you report it as a bug.

Comment: Done - https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23434

Comment: Hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug and `Qt` is working to fix it, in the meantime this is what `Qt` has suggested and it has worked for me. Create a `qtcreator.bat` in the same folder are `qtcreator.exe` with the following contents:

```
@echo off
set QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=Round
qtcreator.exe
```

Launch the .bat file. Not perfect, but at least you can see what's on your screen.

Comment: Another option is to set set QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=PassThrough

Comment: PassThrough creates drawing artifacts for almost all native GUI elements currently if the monitor scale isn't 100% or 200% or 300%  , see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80228

Comment: Did not help on Linux.

Comment: @SergeyGalin, maybe you can report it as a bug to Qt?

Comment: @aalimian Actually, this works:

QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.68 ./qtcreator.sh

And these don't work:

QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1.68

QT_SCALE_FACTOR_ROUNDING_POLICY=(various values)

(Linux, QtCreator 6.0)